# How to use the FTGL C API from C++?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, opengl, ftgl

How do I use [FTGL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ftgl/)'s C API from C++ code in Visual Studio 2010?

[FTGL uses `#ifdef __cplusplus` checks](http://sourceforge.net/p/ftgl/code/1266/tree/trunk/src/FTGL/ftgl.h#l50) to export C and C++ APIs from the same header files.

I tried this:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
  #undef __cplusplus
  #include <FTGL/ftgl.h>
  #define __cplusplus
#else
  #include <FTGL/ftgl.h>
#endif
```

But VS2010 isn't having it:

```
warning C4117: macro name '__cplusplus' is reserved, '#undef' ignored
warning C4117: macro name '__cplusplus' is reserved, '#define' ignored
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do that? Since FTGL's header will detect `__cplusplus` itself, why do you need to lie to it by saying you're looking at the header from C code? Let the header do it's job.

Comment: Because I want to use the *C* API in C++ code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I use FTGL's C API from C++ code in Visual Studio 2010?

You don't.

The makers of FTGL apparently don't want C++ users to use the C API. So they don't let them.

The `__cplusplus` macro is a part of the C++ language; it *cannot* be undefined. Or defined. Or redefined. And since that's what FTGL keys off of, there's no way to trick it into compliance.

The only way to avoid this is to edit FTGL itself.

Answer (score 2):

The macro `__cplusplus` is a reserved macro, and should be *defined automatically* by your compiler if you're compiling as C++ code (and not defined otherwise). You shouldn't have to `#define` it manually, and that's why your compiler throws an error.